# Python Re: Overwrite Issue

Tags: python, regex

I am having an issue with replacing a part of a string. Right now this code. My goal is for every string that includes a key in this dictionary.

```
mapping = { "St": "Street",
            "St.": "Street",
            'Rd': 'Road',
            'Rd.': 'Road',
            'Ave': 'Avenue',
            'Ave.': 'Avenue',
            'Ln':'Lane',
            'Ln.':'Lane',
            'Dr':'Drive',
            'Dr.':'Drive',
            'Pl':'Place',
            'Pl.':'Place',
            'Pkwy':'Parkway',
            'Blvd.': 'Boulevard',
            'Blvd': 'Boulevard'
            }
```

To replace that part of the string with the value in the dictionary.

```
street_type_re = re.compile(r'\b\S+\.?$', re.IGNORECASE)
def update_name(name, mapping):
    for key,value in mapping.iteritems():
        if key in name:
            newname = re.sub(street_type_re,value,name)
            print name,'==>',newname
    return name
```

Right now the code is doing stuff like this

```
National Rd SW ==> National Rd Road
```

I need to fix it so that it returns this

```
National Rd SW ==> National Road SW
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newname = re.sub(key,value,name)
```

You can simply replace `key` instead of matching it with precompiled regex or

```
newname = re.sub(r"\b"+key+r"\b",value,name)
```

Yours replaces the last as you have `$`

Comment: Does that work with partial strings? ex: Hyde St == > Hyde St, State St ==> Streetate Street?

Comment: @user3590113 so `state` should change to `streettate` ?

Comment: No i'm worried about that happening. I that danger covered with your answer?

Comment: I just ran it. That's exactly what happened. North High Street ==> North High Streetreet

Comment: The second part of your answer worked though so i'll give it to you.

Comment: @user3590113 d second part will make sure it doesnt happen